# Geolocation on phonegap returning undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

I want to call a geolocation function from a button in my phonegap application.
Here's the function that I call with the click of the button.

```
function geolocalization () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(searchstructures, showError, {timeout:60000});
        }
        else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by your device.");
        }
    }

    function showError(error) {
        switch(error.code) {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                alert("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
        }
        $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
        $('#searchresult').css('display', 'none');
        $('#formish').css('display', 'block');  
    }

    function searchstructures(position) {
        $('#formish').css('display', 'none');
        $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
        alert (position.coord);
        ...
        AJAX CALL
        ...
    }
```

the config.xml file also contains this

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"/>
</feature>
```

but I always get undefined as position result (the alert in the success function always print undefined).
Any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
function searchstructures(position) {
        $('#formish').css('display', 'none');
        $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
        alert(position.coords.latitude + " " + position.coords.longitude);
}
```

[Check the doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/master/doc/index.md)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Comment: Change coord for coords